# Запретить переход по ссылке, если было движение мышкой

Tags: javascript, jquery

Как зафиксировать движение мышкой при нажатой, но еще не отжатой левой кнопке, (а еще лучше движение мышкой вправо\влево)?
Чтобы применить как-то так:

```
$(".myblock a").on('click', function(){
  if ( /* тут понять было ли движение мышкой*/ ){
    return false;
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Когда вы кликаете по кнопке, происходит 3 инвента: `mousedown`, `mouseup` и уже потом `click` (перечислены в порядке срабатывания)

см. пример:

```js
const button = document.querySelector('button')

button.onclick = () => {
  console.log('click')
}

button.onmousedown = () => {
  console.log('mousedown')
}


button.onmouseup = () => {
  console.log('mouseup')
}
```

```html
<button>click me</button>
```

Вам нужно отлавливать ивент `mousemove` непосредственно после срабатывания `mousedown`

```js
const button = document.querySelector('button')

button.onmousedown = () => {
  //при нажатии добавляем обработчики
  button.onclick = clickHandler; //можно отслеживать как click, так и mouseup
  button.onmousemove = mouseMoveHandler;
}



const clickHandler = () => {
  console.log('Клик!')
  removeEvents()
}

const mouseMoveHandler = () => {
  console.log('Шевелишь!')
  //удаляем обработчики
  removeEvents()
}

const removeEvents = () => {
  button.onclick = null
  button.onmousemove = null
}
```

```html
<button>click me</button>
```