# Запрет открытия модального окна или ссылки на слайдере при перелистывании мышкой объектов слайдера

Tags: javascript, html, css, html5

Подскажите, как сделать запрет открытия модального окна или ссылки на слайдере при перелистывании мышкой объектов слайдера.
При перелистывании срабатывает клик при отпускании кнопки мыши.

```html
<div class="slider">
<div class="tiles">
  <div class="tile">отменить клик если было движение<img src="#" class="image-autofocus"></div>
</div>
<div class="tiles">
  <div class="tile">отменить клик если было движение<img src="#" class="image-autofocus"></div>
</div>
<div class="tiles">
  <div class="tile">отменить клик если было движение<img src="#" class="image-autofocus"></div>
</div>
<div class="tiles">
  <div class="tile">отменить клик если было движение<img src="#" class="image-autofocus"></div>
</div>
</div>
```

Не силен в JS только учусь, не судите строго

Comment: Так а тут и нет JS...

Comment: да по этому и не добавил код, так как не силен в этом, как решить задачу эту не знаю правда

Comment: Не видя ваш код, мало кто знает, что там у вас написано и как оно работает, поэтому и помочь мало кто сможет(лишь тот, кто знает, как выглядит ваш код - а это вы)

Comment: дело втом что js кода и нет, по этому прошу помощи, не знаю как это реализовать

Comment: в этом вопросе есть решение, но я незнаю как его реализовать  https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1318939/%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%85%D0%BE%D0%B4-%D0%BF%D0%BE-%D1%81%D1%81%D1%8B%D0%BB%D0%BA%D0%B5-%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%B1%D1%8B%D0%BB%D0%BE-%D0%B4%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BC%D1%8B%D1%88%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B9 в этом решении используется кнопка у в моем вопросе div class tile вызывает модальное окно.

Comment: SwaD  весь код невозможно здесь добавить, как  добавить? и сам код js для <div class="tiles"> чтобы при перелистывании горизонтального слайдера мышкой если было движение не открывать модальное окно, только при клике на него без движения?